# Do an jquery .attr("href", "new url") on sevral objects not just one

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, jquery-attributes

I have a site that uses for example html element `id="some_id"` several times  and I want to change all those elements with jquery, but when I run the jquery code: `$("#some_id").attr("href", "new url");` Or for example `$("#some_id").text("new text")` I only change the first element/object/link.

Like this:

```
<a id="username">username1</a>
<a id="username">username1</a>
```

Jquery that edit the first element:

```
$("#username").text("username2");
```

How do I edit both elements with jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have duplicate IDs.

Make them a class instead.

```
<a class="username">username1</a>
<a class="username">username1</a>
```

```
$(".username").text("username2");
```

---

Or make the IDs unique:

```
<a id="username_1">username1</a>
<a id="username_2">username1</a>
```

```
$('a[id^="username_"]').text("username2");
```

This one uses the [`attribute-starts-with-selector`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to select `<a>` elements where the ID begins with `username_`.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you can only use an ID once on each page, and only one of your elements is getting selected in the first place. Use a class instead.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, having two elements with the same `id` is invalid HTML. Instead, give them both the same `class` attribute:

```
<a class="username">username1</a>
<a class="username">username1</a>
```

Then, use the following JavaScript:

```
$('.username').text('username2');
```

However, your code example doesn't match your title, so this won't change the `href` of the anchor tags, just their text. To change the `href` of both, call `attr` as you have in the title of this question.